# Macro F1 result higher than accuracy for imbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, class-imbalance, f1score

In one of the research papers on fake news detection, the authors collected a fake news binary dataset (fake vs. real news) consists of `16,817` real articles and `5,323` fake ones.

The authors presented the results using accuracy, precision, recall and F1 without specifying which kind of averaging they applied on the F1 metric (`macro`, `micro`, `weighted`, etc.).

Here are the results:

[image]

If you can notice for the last system, the accuracy value is `0.689` and the F1 value is `0.717` which is higher than the accuracy.

Thus, give the imbalanced status of the dataset, is it possible that the authors averaged the classes in the F1 metric using `macro` way?

For me, this "impossible" to happen, and I argue that probably they used `weighed` F1 score.

Answer (score 1):

They calculated the "standard" F1 score as defined for binary classification tasks:

```
precision = 0.656
recall = 0.792
f1 = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
f1
```

gives

```
0.7176132596685083
```

Other versions of the F1 score are used for multiple classes as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) under "Extension to multi-class classification":

> The F-score is also used for evaluating classification problems with more than two classes (Multiclass classification). In this setup, the final score is obtained by micro-averaging (biased by class frequency) or macro-averaging (taking all classes as equally important). For macro-averaging, two different formulas have been used by applicants: the F-score of (arithmetic) class-wise precision and recall means or the arithmetic mean of class-wise F-scores, where the latter exhibits more desirable properties.

Alternatively, see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) for the scikit learn implementation of the F1 score and its parameter description.

Comment: what do you mean by `standard` F1? the issue is also regarding precision & recall. I mean, to extract precision & recall you have to do `averaging` for the classes.

Comment: @Ghanem I mean the F1 score as I defined in the code of my answer ($F1 = 2\times(precision\times recall) / (precision + recall)$). That is the standard definition for binary classification tasks. [Precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) do not require averaging in a binary task either: $precision = TP / (TP + FP)$ and $recall = TP / P$ where $TP$ stands for true positives, $FP$ for false positives and $P$ for all positives. As for the F1 score you only need averages or weights for multi-class-tasks - not for binary.

Comment: Have a look on this code: from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
    y_true = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    predicted = [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
    print(f1_score(y_true, predicted, average='binary'))
    print(f1_score(y_true, predicted, average='weighted'))
    print(f1_score(y_true, predicted, average='macro'))

Comment: @Ghanem have a look at the scikit learn documentation and the `average` parameter description: *"This parameter is required for **multiclass/multilabel targets**. If None, the scores for each class are returned. Otherwise, this determines the type of averaging performed on the data"*. The default is `average="binary"` which is what I referred to as "standard".

Comment: Ah ok, you mean `standard=binary`. This is different. Anyway `macro` with binary dataset gives different result comparing to `binary`.

Comment: @Ghanem no, it is not just the default in scikit learn but the definition of the F1 score for binary classification problems. if you read about an F1 score in binary classification this is what it refers to (unless explicitly defined differently). Just as the authors do in the paper you asked about.